# Select distinct categories from a table

Tags: sql, excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a table:

```
------------------
| A | B | C | D  |
------------------
| 1 | 5 |bla|bla1| 
------------------
| 2 |10 |bla2|bla2| 
------------------
| 3 |10 |bla2|bla1| 
------------------
| 4 | 5 |bla|bla2|
------------------
```

I know that I can execute a query like: `select distinct * from D`. Therefore I want to have all distinct strings from the column `D`.

What are possible ways to execute this query in Excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not at all sure which solution you would prefer (SQL, VBA, Excel formula) but I think a 'spreadsheet' one is:

[image: SO17727028 example]

Comment: Do you know a formula to get all these distinct data, because I need to process data...